# how to get images defined in loaded sprite sheet asset with Pixijs

Tags: javascript, canvas, pixi.js

Using Pixijs I can Load assets as below:

```
var assetsToLoader = ["sprite-sheet-1.json", "sprite-sheet-2.json"];
loader = new PIXI.AssetLoader(assetsToLoader);
loader.onComplete = onAssetsLoaded
loader.load();
function onAssetsLoaded () {
   // getAssets here  
}
```

in sprite-sheet-1.json

```
{"frames": {

    "image1.png":
    {
        "frame": {"x":0,"y":0,"w":40,"h":40},
        "rotated": false,
        "trimmed": false,
        "spriteSourceSize": {"x":0,"y":0,"w":40,"h":40},
        "sourceSize": {"w":40,"h":40}
    },
    "image2.png":
    {
        "frame": {"x":40,"y":0,"w":40,"h":40},
        "rotated": false,
        "trimmed": false,
        "spriteSourceSize": {"x":0,"y":0,"w":40,"h":40},
        "sourceSize": {"w":40,"h":40}
    }},
    "meta": {
        "app": "http://www.texturepacker.com",
        "version": "1.0",
        "image": "../img/sprite-sheet-1.png.png",
        "format": "RGBA8888",
        "size": {"w":279,"h":40},
        "scale": "1",
        "smartupdate": "$TexturePacker:SmartUpdate:9e3e5afd01ea8e418afabfbdcd724485$",
        "extraMeta": "this is Extra"
    }
}
```

How can I get the list of images defined in sprite sheets programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PIXI stores all your sprites in the global object `PIXI.TextureCache`.

```
function onAssetsLoaded () {
   // getAssets here  
   console.log(PIXI.TextureCache);
}
```

So to get a single texture, you could do something like

```
var texture1 = PIXI.TextureCache["image1.png"];
```

You generally won't ever need to do this though, because adding a Sprite is as simple as

```
var sprite = PIXI.Sprite.fromFrame("image1.png");
```